# Changing a mutable value in a class inheriting from a sealed class with an immutable value

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, immutability, mutability

In Kotlin, I'm trying to have a mutable generic value in sealed class A, and a mutable generic Number value in sealed class B with a mutable Long/... value in final C/...; but whenever I change A and B's values to "var" it gives me: `Var-property type is T, which is not a type of overridden public open var value: Number`.

Example:

```
sealed class Data<T>(
    open val name: String,
    open var value: T
)

sealed class NumberData<T: Number>(
    override val name: String,
    override var value: T
): Data<Number>(name, value)

class TextData(name: String, override var value: String) : Data<String>(name, value)
class LongData(name: String, override var value: Long) : NumberData<Long>(name, value)
// class ...Data(name: String, value: ...) : Data<...>(name, value)

fun main() {
    val dataSet = setOf<Data<*>>(TextData("a1", "hello, world"), LongData("a2", 50024))
    val translate = "a1 a2 c3"

    // Goal: Translate "a1 a2 c3" into a string using dataSet values while ignoring those that aren't in the set.
    // "a1 a2 c3" -> "a1's value a2's value"

    buildSet {
        val map = dataSet.associateBy { it.name }
        for(name in translate.split(" ")) {
            if(map.containsKey(name)) {
                add(map[name]!!.apply { value = 5 }) // "val" cannot be reassigned
                // cannot change val to var in Data as NumberData will give a compiler error:
                // Var-property type is T, which is not a type of overridden public open var value: Number
            }
        }
    }.joinToString(" ") { it.value.toString() }
}
```

Why is this, and how would I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NumberData<T>` inherits from `Data<Number>`, not `Data<T>`, so the type of `value` is expected to be `Number`, not `T`.

It is possible to override a read-only property with a subtype, e.g.

```
open class Foo(
    open val x: Number
)

open class Bar(
    override val x: Int
): Foo(x)
```

This is the case when you do `override val value: T`. `T` is a subtype of `Number`.

This is because someone accessing an instance of `Bar` via `Foo` can still access `x` without breaking anything.

```
val f: Foo = Bar(100)
val number: Number = f.x // 100 is a Number, so everything is fine
```

However, if `x` can be set, this would break:

```
val f: Foo = Bar(100)
// Foo.x declares a setter that takes a Number. Double is a Number, so this should be possible
// But what this actually does though, is that it sets Bar.x at runtime, which is an Int!
f.x = 2.5
```

You probably meant for `NumberData<T>` to inherit `Data<T>` instead.

---

It is also not possible to set the `value` of a `Data<*>`. This is because you don't know what the exact type of `Data` it is. Is it a `Data<String>`? `Data<Long>`? Or `Data<SomethingElse>`? If you don't know that, how would you know that `value` can take the value `5`?

To do what you're trying to do, you don't need to set the `value` at all. You can just do:

```
val map = dataSet.associate { it.name to it.value }
val result = translate
    .split(" ")
    .mapNotNull { map[it]?.toString() }
    .joinToString(" ")
println(result)
```